# FullCalendar-vue + Typescript: Property 'getApi' does not exist

Tags: typescript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar-vue with Typescript and I run into an error when accessing its API.

My calendar is set up like so:

```
<FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar" :options="calendarOptions" style="width: 100%" />
```

And for convenience I use a computed property to make the API available through my whole component:

```js
computed: {
  calendar() {
    return this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi() // Property 'getApi' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
  },
}
```

As you can see, I get the following error:

`Property 'getApi' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.`

I don't know how to tell VS Code that `this.$refs.fullCalendar` is a `Calendar` instance.

Comment: Why did you put `ref="fullCalendar"` in the `<fullCalendar` declaration? That's not shown on any of the examples at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue. It appears to be unnecessary. I don't know for sure if that will help you, but it's probably a good idea to stick to the documentation examples at least until you get the basics working.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your reply. See the end of this same page where it states "Calendar API". This is exactly how it's supposed to be done when you need to use the API to control the calendar (using the date navigation methods).

Comment: Ok sorry. In that case I can't really help you more, perhaps someone who understands Vue fully can assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:

```ts
computed: {
  calendar() {
    return (this.$refs.fullCalendar as InstanceType<typeof FullCalendar>).getApi()
  },
}
```

If you're using composition API:

```ts
  ...
  const fullCalendar = ref<InstanceType<typeof FullCalendar>>()
```

---

[`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) is a utility type to get the result type of the class instantiation.

Comment: It does work! How is that "quick and dirty" though? Also, would you mind sharing what `InstanceType` does?

Comment: "quick and dirty" because `vue` should have some proper way to type `$refs`. But I'm not aware whether it exists. `as` typecast is the last resort usually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time. I'll accept this as the correct answer since it does solve my problem. :)

Comment: @aleksxor could you please make the example for composition API clearer with more details? Used the code and got [this](https://ibb.co/9wgx7bT) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

rather than doing this in a computed property, i found success in setting it in the `mounted()` function.

```
<template>
  <FullCalendar ref="calendar" :options="calendarOptions" />
</template>

...

  data() {
    return {
      calendarApi: null,
    }
  }
...
  mounted() {
     this.calendarApi = this.$refs.calendar.getApi();
  }
```

i'm then able to use this to refresh the calendar data by calling a custom function in `methods`:

```
refetchEvents() {
  this.calendarApi.refetchEvents();
}
```

i'm not sure if this is your use case for the API, but i hope this helps!