# How to fetch data when click on prev and next button on fullcalendar in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, vuejs3, fullcalendar-5

I want to fetch calendar data from database to my Vue frontend, for that I have used fullcalendar API.

I am able to fetch data of current week but when I click on next and previous week at time I stuck as not able to fetch the data.

Please provide me some suggestion or reference, so I can go through it and implement.

Comment: Can you post code ? What you tried so far ?

Comment: To fetch data for different time periods, you need to configure an event source - e.g. a JSON feed or a callback function - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source. This will ensure that fullCalendar automatically a) fetches only data for the date range currently being displayed, and b) automatically fetches new data for the new date range whenever the calendar's date changes. You don't need to handle the clicks on the previous and next buttons directly...in fact no such events are exposed via the fullCalendar API, precisely because a dynamic event source will already do this job for you

Answer (score 0):

> I have used custom button in fullcalendar

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons

> and referred below Stack Overflow link

[FullCalendar-vue + Typescript: Property 'getApi' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67986411/fullcalendar-vue-typescript-property-getapi-does-not-exist)

And fetched the data from `calendarApi` and used in axios as parameter.

Comment: Well that's one way of doing it, but it would be much better to automate it using an event source, as I described above.

Comment: G8, I will look at that as well. @ADyson 
Thank you for your opnion.